# jquery target html5 markup attributes

Tags: jquery, html, alt

I'm trying to use jQuery to simply add an `.alt` class to alternate `article` blocks within a main `section` as follows:

html5:

```
<section id="content" role="main">

  <h1>Main Title</h1>

  <article id="post-1" class="post-1 post type-post">
    .. article content ..
  </article>

  <article id="post-2" class="post-2 post type-post">
    .. article content ..
  </article>

  <article id="post-3" class="post-3 post type-post">
    .. article content ..
  </article>

</section>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#content article:nth-child(odd)').addClass('alt');
```

Am I missing something...? Surely this should work?!

Comment: It looks like it does work to me - http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/EBWPq/

Comment: XO you're right, it was other content in my jquery file that was blocking it! Thanks, I was pulling my hair out!

Comment: @Jonny Wood - Please make your comment an answer and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code does work, other content in my jQuery file was throwing out problems. See the comments above.